# увеличить скорость работы кода

Tags: python

задание звучит как: 
"Проверьте является ли данное число квадратом какого-то неотрицательного числа." 
Нельзя использовать встроенные функции возведения в степень и `import`
пока мой код выглядит так:

```
def isPerfectSquare(self, n: int) -> bool:
    if n == 0:
        return True
    else:
        for i in range (int(n/2) + 1):
            if i * i == n:
                return True
        return False
```

однако, он не проходит лимит по времени, не знаю, как можно сократить затрачиваемое время

Comment: можно попробовать использовать метод деления на два. Вам нужно два числа - начало и конец диапазона. Одно пусть будет 1 - начало, гарантированно меньше. Второе - n/2. А дальше просто считаете число между ними и смотрите.

Comment: Проверять числа до половины n - слишком много. Если ввести 1_000_001 (не квадрат), то будет проверено в 499 раз больше чисел, чем необходимо для решения.

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете воспользоваться [**Итерационной формулой Герона**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0)

```
def sqrt_(a, st): 
    # реализация формулы Герона для нахождения квадратного корня
    x = (st + a/st)/2
    if x==st:
        return x
    return sqrt_(a, x)

def isPerfectSquare(a):
    sq = sqrt_(a, a>>1)
    if sq==int(sq):
        return True
    return False
```

Пример вызова:
`print (isPerfectSquare(50))`
Вывод:
`False`